# L2TP and multiple interfaces on the machine

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, ipsec, l2tp

We have setup ipsec and l2tp on linux. One question came up (due to firewall management policy) is whether it's possible to have 1 virtual interface instead of one per connected client.
Now we have:

`ppp0     serverip   clientip1

ppp1    serverip   clientip2`

Want to have:
`l2tp_tun   serverip   serverip`
like with OpenVPN's tun interfaces and then to be able to push IP address and route to each client.

Comment: I am not particularly familiar with OpenVPN or if this is what you are trying to acheive, but would it not be possible to offer a ppp ip address assignment using pppd on the other end?

Comment: it seems as long as we have to use ppp with l2tp stack we are forced with 1 virtual interface per connection

Comment: Yeah but PPPD allows you to assign the ppp endpoint a particular IP address, so you can setup ip address assignment in pppd.

Comment: as I said in the main question: we need 1 interface on server-side but PPPD seems to create a new interface for every new connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the interface name `ppp+` in iptables rules to match all interfaces starting with the name `ppp`. This ought to suit your needs.

Comment: not quite what is needed but it will have to do the trick. will it also match, say, ppp15?

Comment: Yes, `ppp15` starts with `ppp`.